# JQuery and event bubbling... AGAIN

Tags: jquery, event-handling, event-bubbling

I am roughly working with the following:

```
var i;
var k = 5;
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#someElement').click(function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        i++;
        if (i >= k) {
            my_function();
        });
    }
});
my_function() {
    alert(i);
    $('#myDisplay').text("You have clicked on '#someElement' " + i + "times");
}
```

'my_function()' fires when I click on '#someElement', as expected, but the alertbox pops up 5 TIMES!!!.

A quick and obvious solution would be to place the contents of my_function() and place them into the if control statement attached to '#someElement', but I am very keen to keep the structure I've outlined, and am sure there's a simple way to do so.

Any ideas?

***UPDATE***

I originally assumed that the problem was with the function call from within my 'click' event. It wasn't, I think the problem may have something to do with the nested 'ajaxComplete' call:

```
var i = 0;

$('document').ready(function () {

    $('<div id="someElement">Click me</div>').appendTo('body');
    $('<div id="myDisplay"></div>').appendTo('body');
    $('#someElement').click(function (e) {
        i++;
        $.get("test.html", function(html)
        {       
            $(html).ajaxComplete(function()
            {
                my_function(i);
            });
        });

    });

});

function my_function(n)
{

    switch (n)
    {

    case 1:
        alert(n);
        $('#myDisplay').text("this is case " + n);
        break
    case 2:
        alert(n);
        $('#myDisplay').text("this is case " + n);
        break
    case 3:
        alert(n);
        $('#myDisplay').text("this is case " + n);
        break

    default:
        alert('A great detective always breaks the case. :)');
        break

    }

}
```

I've omitted the constant 'k', as the case statements render the 'if' statement from the previous example useless. The code above provides a better illustration of the problem I've encountered.

Any help will be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Indent the code properly first.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit based on updated question:**

The issue is that you're calling `$.ajaxComplete()` in your callback. You should get rid of that. The anonymous callback function is all you need.

The purpose of `$.ajaxComplete()` is to setup a default function to run when *any* ajax request completes. If this is what you want, you should take it out of the current callback, and just place it in the `.ready()` call so that it only runs once.

The way you're doing it right now, for each click (and successful response) you're adding *another* identical handler. So after you click 5 times, it now has 5 of the same click handler.

**From the docs:** http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

> Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the ajaxComplete event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxComplete() method are executed at this time.

---

**Original answer**

This must not be your actual code, because it won't run at all the way you have it.

You don't have a `function` declaration for your function. You need to initialize `i` with a value like `0`, and your closing parenthesis for the `click` handler is misplaced.

That said, your code works fine for me when corrected.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/sGWjL/1/

If the alert pops up 5 times for you, then you need to paste more (or actual) code being used.

```
var i = 0;
var k = 5;

$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#someElement').click(function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        i++;
        if (i >= k) {
            my_function();
        }
    });
});

function my_function() {
    alert(i);
    $('#myDisplay').text("You have clicked on '#someElement' " + i + "times");
}​
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt replies! I really like that jsfiddle.net app, by the way. ;)

I'll also make an effort to indent my code before posting.
Aside from the elementary mistake I made with the undeclared variable, the code did indeed work correctly.

I've have edited my original post, to present a code example that's more reflective of the problem I've encountered.

Cheers to all of you. :)

Comment: @Leonard - I updated my answer (see above). Basically you either need to get rid of `.ajaxComplete()`, and just call `my_function()` in your callback, or if you want `.ajaxComplete()`, only call it *once*. Right now you're calling it once for *each* ajax response.